# JavaScript add prototype to existing object

Tags: javascript

```
function abc(){
 this.a = "Hey this is A";   
}

var va = new abc();

va.prototype = function(){
  this.b = 'Hey b is added';
}

console.log(va.b);
```

`va.b` is undefined, I thought I already added it to `va`? since `console.log(va)` is an object if I console before the prototype line. What's wrong with my code above?

Comment: try `abc.prototype = ...` or `va.b = ...`

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @TaoP.R. my console.log(va.b) is undefined, why?

Comment: Did you mean "property", not "prototype"? It should just be `va.b = 'Hey b is added';`

Comment: @Bergi that's add to property, I want to try to add va object to have a prototype.

Comment: @AaronMusktin: `va` object already has a prototype that it does inherit from, which is the `abc.prototype` object. And no, you can't change or add that.

Comment: @Bergi: [True enough](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers): *"This annex describes various legacy features and other characteristics of web browser based ECMAScript implementations. All of the language features and behaviours specified in this annex have one or more undesirable characteristics and in the absence of legacy usage would be removed from this specification."* I do find it **very** strange that they've *added* `__proto__` in a deprecated form.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: They have included these things in the spec to ensure that legacy support is consistent across engines - following a *standard*. Only inconsistent legacy support is worse than no legacy support :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I still find it bizarre. I mean, heck, even IE10 didn't have `__proto__`. So it's not like people could rely on it in the wild, and there's been a nice standard way to do it for 5-6 years now. So why add it *now*, and *require* that browsers support it (as Annex B does). Contrast with `Date` parsing `mm/dd/yyyy` successfully (even in locales where that format is wrong), which works on every browser I've ever tried it on and is relied on by a *shedload* of code (though none written by me :-) ). But isn't in the spec. Bizarre.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: People didn't care whether they could rely on it - they just used it (mostly if they needed to set it). IE simply was not supported by them. It's heavily used in node apps and other environments where it's known to be supported. I guess date parsing was not addressed because no one really cared for it - and hey, there's always been the standard "*Date Time String Format*". Iirc, at least they fixed the timezone issue (compare ES5 and 6 on absent timezone values)

Comment: @Bergi: Of course, V8 could drop it from non-browser builds, and blow up Node. :-) Re the date bug in ES5 -- yup, fixed it, and consequently code can't use that format without a timezone, since some engines will interpret it the ES5 way (GMT), others the ES6/ISO-8601 way (local). ;-) Perhaps in a couple of years... Fixing it was definitely the right thing, it just didn't make sense for that format to be so close to a subset of ISO-8601 but handle that differently.

Comment: FYI, `va.prototype` is just a normal property which happens to have the name "prototype". It has nothing to do with prototypal inheritance if that's what you meant.

Comment: @FelixKling: Somewhere along the way, someone should have said that long before now. `+1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you really just want to add a property to `va`:

```
va.b = "Hey b is added";
```

**If**, though, you want to augment the prototype that `va` already has, you do that through a reference to `va`'s prototype object, which you can get in several ways:

- Given your code above, via `abc.prototype`
- Or on ES5+ browsers, via `Object.getPrototypeOf(va)`

So for instance:

```js
function Abc() {
  this.a = "Hey this is A";
}

var va = new Abc();
snippet.log(va.a); // "Hey this is A"
snippet.log(va.b); // undefined

Abc.prototype.b = 'Hey b is added';

snippet.log(va.b); // "Hey b is added"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that adding a property to the prototype means that all objects using that prototype will inherit that property:

```js
function Abc() {
  this.a = "Hey this is A";
}

var a1 = new Abc();
var a2 = new Abc();

Abc.prototype.b = 'Hey b is added';

snippet.log(a1.b); // "Hey b is added"
snippet.log(a2.b); // "Hey b is added"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: so I can't actually do a1.prototype.b = "set b", but the correct way is do Abc.prototype.b ="set b" ?

Comment: @AaronMusktin: It depends entirely on what end result you want, whether you should modify the *instance* (`vm`, in your question) or the prototype (`abc.prototype`, in your question).

Answer (score 2):

You probably just want to add the property to `va`.

```
va.b = 'Hey b is added';
```

Unless you want a `b` property added to all instances of `abc`, then you can add it to `abc`'s prototype:

```
abc.prototype.b = 'Hey b is added';
```

Comment: I thought can add to va variable since it's point to abc object?

Comment: `va !== abc`, instead `va instanceof abc`

Comment: @AaronMusktin `va` doesn't point to `abc`, it does inherit from `abc.prototype` only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function abc()
    {
        //constructor
        this.a="Hey this is A";
    }
    abc.prototype.b=function()
    {
        //prototype
        this.b='Hey b is added';
    };
    var va=new abc();//Initialization
    va.b();//value for b is assigned to the context
    console.log(va.b);
</script>
```

Comments are provided..

Comment: Now you've created a method that overwrites itself on call. Urghh. If this really was what the OP intended to do, you should at least advise against it.

Comment: @Bergi, my intension was to make him understand the execution flow. He is not clear about that..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the `b` property, because you never called `va.prototype`.

```js
function abc(){
 this.a = "Hey this is A";   
}
var va = new abc();
va.prototype = function(){
  this.b = 'Hey b is added';
};
va.b; // undefined
va.prototype();
va.b; // "Hey b is added"
```

Note that using `prototype` as the name for your method can be confusing (there already are the `prototype` of a function and the `[[Prototype]]` of an object). I recommend choosing another name.

Comment: Please also advise against using "`prototype`" as a name for a method.

Comment: @Oriol, that's funny.  I bet there's a clearer way to accomplish what the OP is trying for though.